# Python 3.2.1 ; Pygame 1.9.2 ; Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.x, pygame

When I attempt to run the following program, I receive a syntax error notification:

```
    balli = "ball.png"
    backgroundi = "background.png"

    import pygame , sys
    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500) , 0 , 32)
    background = pygame.image.load(backgroundi).convert()
    cursor = pygame.image.load(balli).convert_alpha()

    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        screen.blit(background , (0,0)

        x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x -= cursor.get_width()/2
        y -= cursor.get_height()/2

        screen.blit(cursor , (x,y))

        pygame.display.update()
```

The problem seems to persist on the line that begins with "x" with the "x" itself.

Comment: And *which* error exactly? How about a full traceback?

Comment: `screen.blit(background , (0,0))`

Answer (score 4):

There is a `)` missing on the previous line.

An assignment can only be a *statement*.

Happy coding.

Comment: Crap! Thanks and sorry. I always make these crap mistakes and look for literally half an hour and then end up wasting internet space with my question.

Comment: @VaryGEEK - you should use a good python IDE, (for example Netbeans), which would help you prevent such small mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Specifically, `screen.blit(background , (0,0)` should be `screen.blit(background , (0,0))`.